# Removing Tuples From A List Removes Some But Not All

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I must be missing something really obvious.

I have a list of tuples that are (phrase, number) pairs. I want to remove entire tuples that have phrases containing stopwords from my stopwords list.

```
stopwords = ['for', 'with', 'and', 'in', 'on', 'down']
tup_list = [('faucet', 5185), ('kitchen', 2719), ('faucets', 2628),
            ('kitchen faucet', 1511), ('shower', 1471), ('bathroom', 1131),
            ('handle', 1048), ('for', 1035), ('cheap', 960), ('bronze', 807),
            ('tub', 797), ('sale', 771), ('sink', 762), ('with', 696),
            ('single', 620), ('kitchen faucets', 615), ('stainless faucet', 613),
            ('pull', 603), ('and', 477), ('in', 447), ('single handle', 430),
            ('for sale', 406), ('bathroom faucet', 392), ('on', 369),
            ('down', 363), ('head', 359), ('pull down', 357), ('wall', 351),
            ('faucet with', 350)]

for p,n in tup_list:
    print('p', p, p.split(), any(phrase in stopwords for phrase in p.split()))

print(len(tup_list))
for p,n in tup_list:
    if any(phrase in stopwords for phrase in p.split()):
        tup_list.remove((p,n))
        print('Removing', p)
print(len(tup_list))

print([item for item in tup_list if item[0] == 'in'])
```

When I run the above, I get the following print-out:

```
p faucet ['faucet'] False
p kitchen ['kitchen'] False
p faucets ['faucets'] False
p kitchen faucet ['kitchen', 'faucet'] False
p shower ['shower'] False
p bathroom ['bathroom'] False
p handle ['handle'] False
p for ['for'] True
p cheap ['cheap'] False
p bronze ['bronze'] False
p tub ['tub'] False
p sale ['sale'] False
p sink ['sink'] False
p with ['with'] True
p single ['single'] False
p kitchen faucets ['kitchen', 'faucets'] False
p stainless faucet ['stainless', 'faucet'] False
p pull ['pull'] False
p and ['and'] True
p in ['in'] True
p single handle ['single', 'handle'] False
p for sale ['for', 'sale'] True
p bathroom faucet ['bathroom', 'faucet'] False
p on ['on'] True
p down ['down'] True
p head ['head'] False
p pull down ['pull', 'down'] True
p wall ['wall'] False
p faucet with ['faucet', 'with'] True
29
Removing for
Removing with
Removing and
Removing for sale
Removing on
Removing pull down
Removing faucet with
22
[('in', 447)]
```

**My Question**: why doesn't the tuple containing `('in', 447)` get removed? The printout shows `p in ['in'] True` meaning 'in' is in the stopwords list, so why does `tup_list.remove((p,n))` not remove it?

Comment: This is what happens when you delete elements from a list you're iterating over - some elements get missed.  One solution would be to iterate over a copy of the list - `for p,n in tup_list[:]:`.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you. I didn't consider that fact; I was trying to be "efficient" by not creating a new list but clearly shouldn't have in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove an item from the list in place, the indices change. As you iterate over a list that changes, you will see unexpected results.

Here is one solution. It's not the most efficient one, but may suit your needs.

```
remove_indices = []

for i, (p, n) in enumerate(tup_list):
    if any(phrase in stopwords for phrase in p.split()):
        remove_indices.append(i)
        print('Removing', p)

tup_list = [i for j, i in enumerate(tup_list) if j not in remove_indices]
```

Comment: OCD note: `for i in range(len(someseq)):` followed by using `i` to index `someseq` is an anti-pattern. You can use `enumerate` and still unpack directly to useful(-ish) names: `for i, (p, n) in enumerate(tup_list):`